# Error in initializing a float value

Tags: java, floating-point, netbeans-8

Why this is not allowed?

```
float n;
n =  1234567.89;
```

but this is.

```
float n;
n =  (float) 12.3456789;
```

I'm using JAVA 8 and Netbeans 8.0.1.

IDE snapshot below.

[image]

Comment: What is the error message coming from the compiler? Is 1234567.89 really a `float`?

Comment: possible lossy conversion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java treat it as double in first line. `n =  1234567.89` not as float. double is 8 byte and float is 4 byte. 
solution is

```
float n;
n =  1234567.89f;
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, Java interprets literal decimals as `double`, so to enter a float you need to do one of the following:

1. `float n = 1234567.89f;`
2. `float n = (float) 1234567.89;`

Note that doing so may result in a loss of precision.

Comment: That obviously will result in a loss of precision because float can only hold ~7 digits of significance. The nearest representation for it is [1234567.875](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=049050051052053054055046056057)

Comment: I meant in general. For this specific example, some precision will be lost. But if I pick 2.5d vs. 2.5f, there is no immediate difference.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a decimal number as 1234567.89, its interpreted as a **double**.

Float numbers end with a letter **f**. You can define it as below.

```
float n;
n =  1234567.89f;
```

Float is a 32 bit IEEE 754 floating point. Double is a 64 bit IEEE 754 floating point.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
float n;
n =  1234567.89f;
```

This declares your number as being a float value instead of a double value by default.